# Non English character support in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, korean-nlp

I have a dataset with non English characters with both header and the column data are non English (Korean).

I had changed the fonts in Oracle SQL Developer to display non English characters but I could see only the column data is displayed in Korean language but the column header displays as special character so any solution for this?

I tried changing the fonts as well but still issue remains same. Nls is Set to utf16 and utf 8 the nls settings are also changed

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the NLS character set settings for the database; a minimal example of the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; the `SELECT` query you use to retrieve the data; the font settings for SQL Developer; the current, incorrect, output in SQL Developer; and the expected output.

Comment: What is your environment encoding set to - under Window->Preferences->Environment->Encoding?

Comment: It’s set to utf 8

Comment: I believe the problem is with the UI font that the application is using - it doesn't support those characters.

Answer (score 0):

The UI font for the application doesn't support those characters.

As a workaround, our [VS Code Extension for SQL Developer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Oracle.sql-developer) supports that just fine.

[image]